# TorBrowser closes my tab as soon as I hit Enter - why?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I recently updated my TorBrowser bundle, and now the new version apparently randomly denies access to various Web pages.  The pages affected aren't out of the ordinary (for example, I've had this happen using Google and Wikipedia), and sometimes just retyping the URL is enough to get it to work - but sometimes nothing I do will make it work, and there's no discernible pattern to what works and what doesn't.  If I right-click a link and select "Open in New Tab", a new tab opens but immediately closes again, and the list of recently closed tabs only shows a generic "New Tab" listing; if I type or paste a URL into the address bar on an already open tab, that tab gets closed and listed in the closed tabs with the title of the page it had been on before I typed in the new URL, and Tor apparently never tries to access the new URL.  It's as if Tor itself, or the relay I'm currently using, were censoring my attempts before I make them.  What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: How did you update the Tor Browser Bundle? Did you unpack into a new directory and did you overwrite old files? Does this also happen with the current version (3.5.2.1) of TBB?